# How can I correctly parse data from get request

Tags: angular

I have a file server (API) in node that returns JSON files stored on the system. I'm trying to recover these files to feed my angular application.

I'm working on angular 7 I've set up a service for getting these data. This one is injected into my component but I can't store data in a variable

my service :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class RestApiService {

  // Define API
  apiURL = 'http://localhost:8443/CSV/convertcsv.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  /*========================================
    CRUD Methods for consuming RESTful API
  =========================================*/

  // Http Options
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }  

  getTrunkResponse():Observable<HttpResponse<Array<GSXTrunks>>>{
    return this.http.get<Array<GSXTrunks>>(this.apiURL, {observe: 'response'})
  }
}
```

my component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'genband',
  templateUrl: './genband.component.html',
})
export class GenbandComponent implements OnInit { 
  Trunks : Array<GSXTrunks> = [];
  headers: any;



  constructor(public restApi: RestApiService) {} 

 ngOnInit() {
    this.showTrunksConfig();
    }

    showTrunksConfig() {
    this.restApi.getTrunkResponse().subscribe( resp =>  {
        this.Trunks = {... resp.body};
        console.log('test');
        for (let i=0; i<this.Trunks.length; i++){
            console.log("test2: "this.Trunks[i].trunk_name);
        }
     });
  }
}
```

content of convertcsv.json

```
[
    {
      "Trunk_name": "2019/07/02 03:21:57",
      "Busy": 1,
      "Idle": 619,
      "Total": 620,
      "Other": 0
    },
    {
      "Trunk_name": "2019/07/02 03:41:53",
      "Busy": 0,
      "Idle": 620,
      "Total": 620,
      "Other": 0
    },
    {
      "Trunk_name": "2019/07/02 04:01:58",
      "Busy": 1,
      "Idle": 619,
      "Total": 620,
      "Other": 0
    },
    {
      "Trunk_name": "2019/07/02 04:21:55",
      "Busy": 0,
      "Idle": 620,
      "Total": 620,
      "Other": 0
    }
]
```

interface GSXTrunks :

```
export interface GSXTrunks {
   trunk_name: String,
   busy: String,
   idle: Number,
   total: Number,
   other: Number,

}
```

So I try to store the contents of convertcsv in an array of GSXTrunks but when I do not for loop in showTrunksConfig() console.log shows nothing because I think trunks. length still equals zero.
The purpose would be after having stored in the table create again 4 tables respectively containing the values ​​of trunks_name, busy, idle, total, other (a table by a variable) because for the suite I need these separate table to feed a graph. But I'm blocking on recovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trunk_name <===== the _ underscore ...may not working...better replace from server side.
```

## Or,  Try Parsing : JSON.parse(serverResponse)

```
var x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log(x.trunk_name );
```

## service.ts

```
public getTrunkResponse():Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(Url , {}, payload, httpOptions ).pipe(
        map(this.extractData),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            debugger;
            const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'dddsd is..';
            return Observable.throw(errMsg);
        })
    );
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    return res || [];
}
```

## component.ts

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.showTrunksConfig();
        }

        showTrunksConfig() {
    const self = this;
        this.restApi.getTrunkResponse().subscribe(
                success => {
                    console.log(success)  //<==== print here 
                   self.apiData = success //<==== store data in variable globally here
or,
var x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log(x.trunk_name );
                },
                error => { }
            );
      }
```

## .html

```
{{apiData?.key}}  <===== use api data. Use `?` operator to avoid `null` or `undefined` values. use `*ngIf` as well in templates.
```

Comment: Thank you Mahi. It's working perfectly with self.apiData = success. I can get data with apiDAta[i].Trunk_name. I really appreciate

Comment: Glad. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

`this.Trunks` is an object which does not have `length` property. It can be changed to `Object.keys(this.Trunks).length` instead.

```
for (let i=0; i<Object.keys(this.Trunks).length; i++){
    console.log("test2: "this.Trunks[i].trunk_name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lam I can get the right number with object.keys(this.trunks).length . But this.Trunks[i].trunk_name is still undefined. Do you know the right way to record data into my Array<GSXTrunks> ? I want to be able to get data into this.Trunks[i].trunk_name.

Comment: It's `Trunk_name`, not `trunk_name` as i see it's capitalized.